# Javascript parse chat text

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I'm trying to find a way to parse chat text, and I'm having some issues. My purpose is to split the text into the fields (Date, Time, Name, Text) and get a statistic by Name, Date, and get number of words/letter in total for each person.

A sample would be this :

```
 10/06/2019, 23:17 - Nasu Alex Taranu Gilmeanu: De iesit iesim cu siguranta. Dar tre sa cadem de acord la o varianta
 10/06/2019, 23:17 - Dura Stefanel: Serios acum
 10/06/2019, 23:18 - Dura Stefanel: E cea mai frumoasa cazare de pe site: din câte am văzut pana acum
 11/06/2019, 00:04 - Nasu Alex Taranu Gilmeanu: http://www.booking.com/Share-CJY
 11/06/2019, 18:31 - Danutz: Sa îl mănânci - cu Botu :)
```

The code I'm using is the one below, but I can't figure what the regex should be in order for it to:

- split by ": " and not by ":", so the time stays together.
- split only by first occurrence of the specified characters, as the split characters might be in the text to the right as well, and I only want to split the 4 fields

I load the stringData variable form a text file using Ajax, I just added str as a small sample of the data:

```
var stringData = $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost/_FunStuff/_ChatCounter/2021.01.04_textFile.txt",
                    async: false
                 }).responseText;
```

```js
const str = `10/06/2019, 23:17 - Nasu Alex Taranu Gilmeanu: De iesit iesim cu siguranta. Dar tre sa cadem de acord la o varianta
 10/06/2019, 23:17 - Dura Stefanel: Serios acum
 10/06/2019, 23:18 - Dura Stefanel: E cea mai frumoasa cazare de pe site: din câte am văzut pana acum
 11/06/2019, 00:04 - Nasu Alex Taranu Gilmeanu: http://www.booking.com/Share-CJY
 11/06/2019, 18:31 - Danutz: Sa îl mănânci - cu Botu :)`;

function splitImportedData(stringData) {
  $arrRows = stringData.split("\n");
  for (rowi = 0; rowi < $arrRows.length; rowi++) {
    var $strRow = $arrRows[rowi]
    var $arrRow = $strRow.split(/[,:\s+\-]/);
    if (rowi == 1) {
      console.log($arrRow);
      //alert($arrRow);
    }
  }
}

splitImportedData(str);
```

Answer (score 4):

you need not have to do a split on the row.

```js
const str = `- 10/06/2019, 23:17 - Nasu Alex Taranu Gilmeanu: De iesit iesim cu siguranta. Dar tre sa cadem de acord la o varianta
 - 10/06/2019, 23:17 - Dura Stefanel: Serios acum
 - 10/06/2019, 23:18 - Dura Stefanel: E cea mai frumoasa cazare de pe site: din câte am văzut pana acum
 - 11/06/2019, 00:04 - Nasu Alex Taranu Gilmeanu: http://www.booking.com/Share-CJY
 - 11/06/2019, 18:31 - Danutz: Sa îl mănânci - cu Botu :)`;

const splitImportedData = (stringData) => {
  return stringData.split("\n").map(row => {
    const m = row.match(/^\s*?- (.+?), (.+?) - (.+?): (.+)/);
    return {
      date: m[1],
      time: m[2],
      name: m[3],
      text: m[4],
    }
  });
}

console.log(splitImportedData(str));
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution, but unfortunately I can't get it to work on the original stringData, which I load using ajax from a text file (i will add this part to my original question). 
The error I get is "ddu_ChatCounter_JS.html:690 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'groups' of null". 
If I copy a few lines into your const str, the code works. Can you please take a look at the way I load the text file, and let me know if something is not compatible?

Answer (score 2):

Might I encourage you to use the `.match()` method instead splitting and more parsing. As you'll see, you get the direct result you are seeking:

```js
const str = `- 10/06/2019, 23:17 - Nasu Alex Taranu Gilmeanu: De iesit iesim cu siguranta. Dar tre sa cadem de acord la o varianta\n
 - 10/06/2019, 23:17 - Dura Stefanel: Serios acum\n
 - 10/06/2019, 23:18 - Dura Stefanel: E cea mai frumoasa cazare de pe site: din câte am văzut pana acum\n
 - 11/06/2019, 00:04 - Nasu Alex Taranu Gilmeanu: http://www.booking.com/Share-CJY\n
 - 11/06/2019, 18:31 - Danutz: Sa îl mănânci - cu Botu :)\n`;

function splitImportedData(stringData) {
  const result = [];
  const regex = /(?<date>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}), (?<time>\d{2}:\d{2}) - (?<author>.*(?=:)):\s(?<comment>.*)/;
  stringData.split("\n").filter(s=>s!='').forEach(r => {
    result.push(r.match(regex).groups);
  });
  return result;
}

let res = splitImportedData(str);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **non-capturing groups** in your split regex eg: `/(?:, )|(?:- )|(?:: )/` obviously you can make something smarter but this could help as a basic example.

You can use as ref: [Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges)

Comment: Thank you for the solution, it kind of worked, but I'm getting arrays of different sizes because it's splitting for example everywhere there is a "," character.  Is there anything i can add to a group to only split by the first occurrence of  "," ?